# QTreeWidget columns not visible -- when GUI opens

Tags: qt, qtreeview

I am creating 4 columns in `QTreeWidget` used in my GUI :

Code creating the 4 columns, Columns are created correctly by the following code :

```
void MainWindow::createTreeWidgetView()
{
    QTreeWidgetItem* headerItem = new QTreeWidgetItem();
    headerItem->setText(0,QString("Test Case"));
    headerItem->setText(1,QString("Description"));
    headerItem->setText(2,QString("Floor"));  
    headerItem->setText(3,QString("House"));  

    ui->treeWidgetLeft->setHeaderItem(headerItem);
}
```

Problem I am facing is that all the four columns of `QTreeWidget` are not visible when the GUI opens.

Only first column "Test case" is visible while rest three are hidden (although I can view all the four column by scrolling horizontally `QTreeWidget`).

Please suggest what I have to change in my code that all 4 columns are visible when GUI opens?

[image]

Comment: i assume you have tried `TeeWidget->setVisible(true);`?? or updated the ui after setting the headers to it?

Comment: yes, I have tried this, but it did not worked, only one column is visible -- ui->treeWidgetLeft->setVisible(true); ---

Comment: TeeWidget->Setvisible(true) is not allowing the Treewidget to be streched .. so that all 4 columns are visible ... any suggestion what i am missing .. ?

Comment: `resize()` that should auto resize it perhaps?

Comment: Instead of using Resize() i used .... ui->treeWidgetLeft->resizeColumnToContents(i);  .... for all the columns it resized all the columns to there content width ... but still when GUI opens only one column is visible rest columns are hidden ....

Answer (score 0):

in QTcreator under header property uncheck `headerstrechlastSection`
then it shows all columns